# logback(1.3.0) & slf4j(2.0.0-alpha2) version combination does not work

Tags: java, logback, slf4j, logback-classic

So we get below NoClassDefFoundError if we upgrade slf4j => 1.8.0 or higher.
logback-classic-1.3.0-alpha4.jar
logback-core-1.3.0-alpha4.jar
slf4j-api-1.8.0-alpha2.jar 

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder displayed in logs

**However below existing version combination works**

logback-classic-1.2.3.jar
logback-core-1.2.3.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar

Any idea why slf4j(1.8.0 or higher) does not work when used with logback-classic(1.3.0-alpha4) pls?


Actually we have upgraded as part of our jdk8 => jdk11 upgradation exercise .

Answer (score -1):

logback 1.3.x series require slf4j-api version 2.0.x

[image]

Also, logback-classic natively implements the SLF4J API, so I believe you don't need to add  slf4j-api in your pom.xml explicitly.